# PHP operators if statement 'and' and 'or'

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I have an if statement that I want to control with having one field needing input and they have to pick one of the other 2 choices.

```
if(test1 && test || test3){
//Something here
}
```

Should I do it like this:

```
if(test1 && (test2 || test3)){
//do stuff
}
```

How would I go about doing this. I can't wrap my head around the logic...

Comment: Please read [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if ($requiredField && ($optional1 || $optional2)) {
  /* Do something */
}
```

For the `/* Do something */` bit of code to be executed, the if statement has to evaluate to `TRUE`.

This means, that `$requiredField` must be `TRUE`, and so must be `($optional1 || $optional2)`.

For `$requiredField` to be `TRUE`, it just needs to be filled in - and for the second part: `($optional1 || $optional2)` either `optional1` or `optional2` would do it.

Edit:

After rereading the question, it seems that I might have misunderstood you. If the user **must** enter one specific piece of information, and  **must** choose only **one** (not both) out of two options - then the following should be used.

```
if ($requiredField && ($optional1 ^ $optional2)) {
  /* Do something */
}
```

This means that `$optional1` or `$optional2` must be filled out - but not both of them.

Comment: Nice naming.  Maybe explain why that works since OP didn't understand the logic with using this if statement. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the sound of it, you want the latter:

```
if ($test1 && ($test2 || $test3)){
    //do stuff
}
```

Think of it as two conditions needing to be met.  This gives you those two conditions.  The second condition just happens to be another condition.  The first option you posted, however, is quite the opposite as it can allow execution if just `$test3` is true

Answer (score 2):

`test1 && (test2 || test3)` is very easy to understand from the first place - Choose test1 && (test2 || test3) means one the last two. Very clear.

`test1 && test || test3` - doesn't seem to be correct:

```
test1 = false
test2 = false
test3 = true

false && false || true = true
```

doesn't actually fit your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

> ... they have to pick one of the other 2 choices

I'm just throwing a guess out here. If you really want to ensure that one, but only one of the two other options are selected, then you need [`xor`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if ($required AND ($and_either XOR $or_other)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have 'nested' if statements withing a single if statement, with additional parenthesis.

```
 if(test1 && (test2 || test3)){
    //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is right but your sintax isnt, you should compare the values of the variables as show, or simply ignore them as saying you are trying to compare them as they are TRUE.

```
$test1=true;
$test2=true;
$test3=false;
if($test1==true && ($test2==true || $test3==true){ echo "YES";}
```

This will output YES.

Comment: I think you missed the logic a little bit